# Linq - better `Enumerable.Except()` operator (performance AND flexibility)?

Tags: .net, performance, linq

Let's assume two collections of objects. I want to retrieve the objects in the first collection that are not contained in the 2nd collection.

For collections of primitive types, that's easy:

```
new[]{1,2,3,4}.Except(new[]{2,3}); //  => {1, 4}
```

But what if I want to use a more complex structure? In the example below, I want to compare using the `Id` field.

```
class Person { string Name; int Id ; }

var lst1 = new[]{ new Person("Ann", 1), new Person("Bob", 2) };
var lst2 = new[]{ new Person("Cathy", 3), new Person("Bob", 2) };
```

Well, the general consensus seems to offer these two options:

- `Enumerable.Except()` plus custom `IEqualityComparer<>`, along these lines:

-

```
class IdComparer: IEqualityComparer<Person> { /* boilerplate Equals(), GetHashCode() */ }

lst1.Except(lst2, new IdComparer())
    .Select(p=>p.Name);              // => { "Ann" }
```

This method is cumbersome for defining the equality criteria.

- using a negated `.Contains()` - still needs an `IEqualityComparer<>`; or a negated `.Any()` - this allows specifying the condition inline.

-

```
from p1 in lst1
where ! lst2.Any(p2 => p1.Id == p2.Id)
select p1.Name;                      // => { "Ann" }
```

This is easier to use, but it reads like "for each element in lst1 check each element in lst2" which looks like complexity O(M*N). Not sure if different Linq providers (can) optimize this.

Complexity-wise, the `.Except()` method fares quite a bit better: roughly O(M+N), [as it uses a `Set<>`](http://blog.mariusschulz.com/2011/08/08/why-enumerableexcept-might-not-work-the-way-you-might-expect).

- How about the 'left-outer-join-filtered-by-NULLs' trick from Sql? I didn't find references to this one, so either I didn't search enough, or it's flawed.

-

```
from p1 in lst1
join p2 in lst2 on p1.Id equals p2.Id into grp
where ! grp.Any()
select p1.Name;                     // => { "Ann" }
```

This allows easy comparison using a field.
Also, from what I can tell (digging into the `Enumerable.JoinIterator()` implementation), the complexity is still roughly O(M+N).

Is this a good substitute for `Enumerable.Except()` ?

Comment: You can write a simple projecting `EqualityComparer<T>` so you need to only write the boilerplate once.

Comment: What about overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods of your person class?

Comment: @CodesInChaos True - but the 'outer join' method even allows working with collections of different types, as long as there is a common "key" - and the boilerplate is 0

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`ExceptBy`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/ExceptBy.cs) extension method from moreLINQ library

It allows you to specify the key used to comparision:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> ExceptBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first,
    IEnumerable<TSource> second,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
```

or even specify the equality comparer:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> ExceptBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first,
    IEnumerable<TSource> second,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    IEqualityComparer<TKey> keyComparer)
```

Comment: Nice :) Here's an overview of the [added operators](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview) (`ExceptBy()` is misteriously missing, so I'm guessing the documentation is a bit outdated)

Comment: So how's that implemented? What's the O() ?

Answer (score 0):

I've got a solution, using Except.

Look at this:

```
public class PropertyEqualityComparer<TObject, TProperty> 
    : IEqualityComparer<TObject>
{
    Func<TObject, TProperty> _selector;
    IEqualityComparer<TProperty> _internalComparer;
    public PropertyEqualityComparer(Func<TObject, TProperty> propertySelector,
        IEqualityComparer<TProperty> innerEqualityComparer = null)
    {
        _selector = propertySelector;
        _internalComparer = innerEqualityComparer;
    }
    public int GetHashCode(TObject obj)
    {
        return _selector(obj).GetHashCode();
    }
    public bool Equals(TObject x, TObject y)
    {
        IEqualityComparer<TProperty> comparer = 
            _internalComparer ?? EqualityComparer<TProperty>.Default;
        return comparer.Equals(_selector(x), _selector(y));
    }
}
public static class PropertyEqualityComparer
{
    public static PropertyEqualityComparer<TObject, TProperty>
        GetNew<TObject, TProperty>(Func<TObject, TProperty> propertySelector)
    { 
        return new PropertyEqualityComparer<TObject, TProperty>
            (propertySelector);
    }
    public static PropertyEqualityComparer<TObject, TProperty>
        GetNew<TObject, TProperty>
        (Func<TObject, TProperty> propertySelector, 
        IEqualityComparer<TProperty> comparer)
    { 
        return new PropertyEqualityComparer<TObject, TProperty>
            (propertySelector, comparer);
    }
}
```

Basically what it does is allow you to have an IEqualityComparer that can compare using a selector. You can then just use it like this:

```
lst1.Except(lst2, PropertyEqualityComparer.GetNew(n => n.Id));
```

(sorry for code formatting, on mobile.)